# Zurb Foundation Offcanvas Menu stops working after toggling programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I use Zurb Foundation 5 in a Wordpress Theme with an offcanvas menu, which is working fin in gerneral, but I have come across a problem:

In addition to the hamburger icon in the Top Bar, I give the option to open the menu when clicking on a fixed position div element .back-to-menu. 
To achieve this, I used the method to open the offcanvas menu programmatically as described in Zurb's docs.
While this works fine, after I've clicked on div.back-to-menu to open the menu and then close the menu again, I can't seem to open the menu by clicking on the hamburger icon in the Top Bar any more.

This is the code to open the menu:

```
jQuery('.back-to-menu').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.off-canvas-wrap').foundation('offcanvas', 'show', 'move-right');
    }, duration);
    return false;
})
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Foundation, when I execute your script on the Foundation documentation page the same error occurs, the menu opens and closes but then is broken.

A workaround is to trigger the offcanvas by simulating a click on the hamburger icon:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.off-canvas-wrap').find('.left-off-canvas-toggle').click(); 
}, duration);
```

This isn't as neat as using the "official" way, but this is faily foolproof and certainly better than breaking your menu after using it.

---

Apparently there already is an [issue](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/5793) filed for this at the Foundation GitHub and the same workaround was proposed for so long as it's unfixed.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Still, your suggestion will work fin on my site. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to be that the body class becomes "fixed" I patched mine with some simple css

```
body.fixed { position:static !important}
```